# Could not load file or assembly after installing new NuGet package on another system

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently trying to develop a cross platform supported .NET 5.0 application. I use Visual Studio on Windows to debug and develop, and then I use WSL in the same project folder to run `dotnet publish` with the `--runtime linux-x64` argument.

Even if I remove the `\bin` and `\obj` directories in my project, I get an `Could not load file or assembly` on the newly installed NuGet package, when trying to do `dotnet publish --platform linux-x64` via WSL. Running with F5 in Visual Studio works perfectly fine.

Here's the output:

```
$ dotnet publish -c Release -o publish -p:PublishReadyToRun=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true --self-contained true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --runtime linux-x64 Project.sln
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.1+2fd48ab73 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /mnt/c/Users/morten/Desktop/Project/Project.csproj (in 327 ms).
  Project -> /mnt/c/Users/morten/Desktop/Project/bin/Release/net5.0/linux-x64/Project.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Project -> /mnt/c/Users/morten/Desktop/Project/publish/
```

So as you can see, it takes it 327ms to restore the packages, even after removing the two directories. Something tells me there's an underlying cache hidden somewhere.

I tried doing `dotnet restore` as well as `--force`, but the time to restore is still roughly the same. If I do `cat *.csproj` I can definitely see my new NuGet package.

I tried clearing the NuGet cache by doing `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`, but that didn't help either. It took about 5 seconds to restore the packages this time, though.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: launchsettings.json ?

Comment: @T.S. What about it? Contains nothing worth mentioning

Comment: your error sounds like runtime stuff and should not be dependent on the package at all. Because at runtime you use dll that was picked by self-contained... btw, are you sure your command is correct `--self-contained true`. I think should be `--self-contained=true`

Comment: @T.S. It sounds like a runtime error indeed, which I don't really understand, as the package is in my csproj. `--self-contained true` is correct